# residue theorem, laurent espansion, singularities and order of poles

Tags: laurent-series

[image]

for this question i have found that for part

(i) at $z=0$ we have an essential singularity

**however, I'm not sure how to solve for the residual?**

(ii) at $z=0$ we have a pole of order $2$, and i have found the residual to be $1$

(iii) at $z=0$ we have an essential singularity

*** however, again I'm not sure how to solve for the residual? ***

Comment: never heard of an essential pole before.

Comment: essential singularity, my mistake i will edit

Comment: @jimmy  OK.  All done.  See my answer for explanations.  And please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2n+1}$$

The residue is the coefficient on the $z^{-1}$ term, which here is 1.

---

Using partial fraction expansion, we see that

$$\frac{z+2}{z^2(z+1)}=\frac{-1}{z}+\frac{2}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z+1}$$

The residue is the coefficient on the $z^{-1}$ term, which here is -1.

---

$$\begin{align}
\frac{z(e^z-e^{-z})}{1-\cos z}&=\frac{z\sinh z}{\sin^2 (z/2)}\\\\
&=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!}}{\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z/2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{z^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}{(z/2)^2\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z/2)^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}{\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z/2)^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2}
\end{align}$$

The leading term in the series of the denominator is $1$.  Thus, the function of interest has no singularity at $z=0$ and therefore, the residue is $0$.  In fact, the limit as $z \to 0$ of the function of interest is $4$.

Comment: Laurent series expansion is very difficult for (iii)

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 One doesn't need the Laurent series to compute the residue. One only needs the coefficient on the $z^{-1}$ term.  For (iii), that coefficient is $0$ since the series in the denominator is not $0$ for $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For (i), $Res(f,0)=$coefficient of $z^{-1}=1$ , using Laurent series expansion of $\sin(1/z)$.

(iii) $Res(h,0)=\lim_{z\to 0}zh(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z^2(e^z-e^{-z})}{1-\cos z}$ , as at $z=0$ $h$ has simple pole.

(ii) $Res(g,0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}(z-0)^mg(z)$ , for pole of order $m(>1)$ at $z=0$.

Comment: for (iii) would that simply be $0$? surely we'd have to use Laurents expansion again as we have $\cos(z)$ in the denominator?

Comment: Just find the limit.....Limiting value is the answer...I don't know what is the answer....I think you can find it.

Comment: One needs to know the order of the singularity to apply the formula you referenced for calculating the residue.  Here, that order is zero and the formula doesn't even apply inasmuch as the residue is zero.